# filtering dataframe based on date and time (in 2 separate columns)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below pandas `dataframe` that I am trying to filter, to provide me with an updated `dataframe` based on the last `date & time` in my database.

This is a sample of the `dataframe` I am trying to filter:

```
>>> df
  # The time is in '%H:%M:%S' format, and the date is in '%d-%b-%Y'
  Time      Date          Items
  00:05:00  29-May-2018   foo
  00:06:00  30-May-2018   barr
  00:07:00  31-May-2018   gaaa
  00:11:00  31-May-2018   raaa
  ...       ...           ...
```

What I am trying to do, is to filter this `dataframe` based on the last entry in my sql database. For example, the last entry is: `['20:05:00','30-May-2018']`. The below code is what I used to filter out from `df`:

```
last_entry = ['20:05:00','30-May-2018']
# Putting time into a datetime format to work within the dataframe.
last_entry_time = datetime.strptime(last_entry[0], '%H:%M:%S').time()
new_entry = df[(df['Date'] >= last_entry[1]) & (df['Time'] > last_entry_time)]
```

If I were to just have the filter as: `new_entry = df[df['Date'] >= last_entry[1])]` instead, this works well to return the current date and newer based on the last date, which is: `30-May-2018` and `31-May-2018`.

However, regarding the time portion, because my `last_entry` time is `20:05:00`, it starts to filter out the rest of the data that i'm trying to collect...

**Question:**

How can I perform the filter of the `dataframe`, such that it returns me the new entries in the dataframe, that is based off the old `date and time` in the database?

**Ideal result**

```
last_entry = ['20:05:00','30-May-2018']
>>> new_entry

  Time      Date          Items
  00:07:00  31-May-2018   gaaa
  00:11:00  31-May-2018   raaa
  ...       ...           ...
```

Comment: Why don't you use `23:59:59` as your time in `last_entry`?

Comment: Because the `last_entry` date and time is something that will be picked up from the database. It is a dynamic entry that will change daily after the update. For this example, I hardcoded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a datetime column in your DataFrame, and then filter on this column, for example:

```
df["real_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d-%b-%Y")
df["real_time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"])
df["real_datetime"] = df["real_date"] + df["real_time"]
```

You also need to convert your `last_entry` variable to a proper datetime, for example like this:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from datetime import datetime


date = parse(last_entry[1], dayfirst=True)
time_elements = [int(t) for t in last_entry[0].split(":")]
last_entry_dt = datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, time_elements[0], time_elements[1], time_elements[2])
```

Then you can filter the new DataFrame column like so:

```
df[df["real_datetime"] >= last_entry_dt]
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. Haven't got the time to try this until now. Regarding `time_elements`, I get what you are trying to perform, however, the `time` in the database seems to be `%H:%M:%S.%f` format. So `split{':')` didn't work because of the `%f` portion. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's okay. I managed to solve it by adding a code to remove the `.f` element before parsing `time_elements`!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!